# Strtol() and atol() do not convert strings larger than 9 digits

Tags: c, string, long-integer

while working on an application that requires converting strings to long numbers the atol() and strtol() could not convert any string larger than 9 digits correctly.

strtol would prompt a number that has nothing to do with the string, while atol results in a negative number (overflow).

any idea why this is happening and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This probably has to do with the size of a `long` on your platform. On 32-bit platforms, the largest value that fits in a `long` is 2147483647 (2^31-1), so anything larger than that simply won't fit. Use `long long` and `strtoll` instead.

Comment: ya thats the number that strtol gives me , so it gotta be the platform's limitation, strtoll worked thanks alot!

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like a `long` on your system is a 32-bit value.  That means any unsigned number above 4,294,967,295 won't convert correctly, and neither will signed numbers above 2,147,483,647 or below 2,147,483,648.

In general, an *n*-bit representation can represent signed numbers in the range [-2<sup>*n*-1</sup>,-2<sup>*n*-1</sup>) or unsigned numbers in the range [0,2<sup>*n*</sup>).

The wikipedia article [Computer numbering formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_numbering_formats) is probably a good jumping off point to learn more about this behaviour.

The reason you see different results from `atol()` and `strtol()` is because they have different error handling characteristics.  From the [`strtol()` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol):

> The **`strtol()`** function returns the result of the conversion, unless the value would underflow or overflow. If an underflow occurs, **`strtol()`** returns **`LONG_MIN`**. If an overflow occurs, **`strtol()`** returns **`LONG_MAX`**. In both cases, **`errno`** is set to **`ERANGE`**.

And from the [`atol()` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atol):

> The **`atoi()`** function converts the initial portion of the string pointed to by **`nptr`** to int. The behaviour is the same as
>
> ```
> strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10);
> ```
>
> except that **`atoi()`** does not detect errors.
>
> The **`atol()`** and **`atoll()`** functions behave the same as **`atoi()`**, except that they convert the initial portion of the string to their return type of **`long`** or **`long long`**.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably converting to a 32-bit integer. There are libraries to work around this.

Try using [libgmp](http://gmplib.org/), it will impose no limit on the size of your integer.

Comment: Yes, your program will just get `abort`'ed without your consent if the integer is too big...